# Intregration Paypal Pro payment

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I need to integrate the PayPal Pro in my iOS app instead of PayPal i.e being used in the my current app.

I couldn't find any documentation for integrate the PayPal Pro in iOS app.

Is there any difference between PayPal and PayPal Pro integration and therefor different iOS SDK.

Thanks in advance.